# Sailsjs changing route policies order

Tags: sails.js

My config/policies.js

```
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': ['tokenValidate'],
};
```

My config/routes.js

```
'POST /users': [ { policy: 'onlyAdmin' }, { action: 'users/create' } ],
```

With this config when i send a POST to /users, first the request stops on onlyAdmin policy -> tokenValidate policy -> users/create action, to solve my problem i need to call tokenValidate before onlyAdmin policy.

If i use the code bellow tokenValidate is called twice.

```
'POST /users': [ { policy: 'tokenValidate' }, { policy: 'onlyAdmin' }, { action: 'users/create' } ],
```

I already read the docs but found nothing, someone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to include the policy as an array:

```js
// config/policies.js

module.exports.policies = {
  '*': 'tokenValidate',
  'folder/file-or-*': ['tokenValidate', 'onlyAdmin']
};
```

Check `Policy ordering and precedence` in the documentation:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies

An alternative is to use a `hook` for the token validation and a policy for the permission:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/hook-specification

Or a helper:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/access-control-and-permissions